# Is there a legal video size limit for Super Bowl parties?

Tags: united-states, law, television

[Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/recycled/2010/02/is_my_super_bowl_party_illegal.html) claims:

> A Baptist congregation in Indiana plans to cancel its Super Bowl party this weekend, after receiving a threatening letter from the National Football League. NFL officials say the church would have broken the law by charging an admission fee and by screening the game on a TV that exceeds 55 inches.

Is showing the [Super Bowl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl) on a television screen over a certain size, to a group, illegal without permission?

Has the NFL, or other relevant authority, ever pursued someone for projecting the Super Bowl on a large screen (in particular, a religious group)?

Comment: It seems like the answer you are looking for is clearly laid out in the article you linked to.  What more are you looking for?

Comment: @Qes corporations often claim things are illegal in order to stop people from doing something. It doesn't mean they are right.

Comment: Are you asking whether Slate made this story up? Because unless they did, your last question is answered.

Comment: Here are some links that repeat what Slate says: http://www.mpaa.org/contentprotection/types-of-content-theft http://digitivity.org/785/will-the-nfl-put-you-in-jail-for-illegal-superbowl-party-55-inch-tv http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/news/2010/01/will-your-big-screen-super-bowl-party-violate-copyright-law.ars

Comment: @SonnyOrdell - that's a valid point, but whether the company was within its legal rights can only be answered by a court, not by SE answer :)

Comment: @SonnyOrdell: The relevant US law is also referenced in the article.

Comment: btw. *"not more than 4 loudspeakers are located in any 1 room"* rule is easier to brake, any 5.1 surround-sound system has at least 6 of them.

Comment: The issue that got the NFL's attention is the charging a fee for showing an NFL-owned broadcast (without cutting in the NFL), I would think.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[US Code Title 17, Chapter 1, § 110. LIMITATIONS ON EXCLUSIVE RIGHTS: EXEMPTION OF CERTAIN PERFORMANCES AND DISPLAYS](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/html/uscode17/usc_sec_17_00000110----000-.html)

> (4) performance of a nondramatic literary or musical work otherwise
>   than in a transmission to the public, without any purpose of direct or
>   indirect commercial advantage and without payment of any fee or other
>   compensation for the performance to any of its performers, promoters,
>   or organizers, if—
>
> [...*lots of other rules*...]
>
> if the performance or display is by audiovisual means, any visual
>   portion of the performance or display is communicated by means of a
>   total of not more than 4 audiovisual devices, of which not more than 1
>   audiovisual device is located in any 1 room, and **no such audiovisual
>   device has a diagonal screen size greater than 55 inches**, and any
>   audio portion of the performance or display is communicated by means
>   of a total of not more than 6 loudspeakers, of which not more than 4
>   loudspeakers are located in any 1 room or adjoining outdoor space;

However, private viewing in private house is exempt from these rules, so at home you can have as big TV as you'd like. This includes having a private Super Bowl party at home.

Read more in [ArsTechnica: "Will your big-screen Super Bowl party violate copyright law?"](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/news/2010/01/will-your-big-screen-super-bowl-party-violate-copyright-law.ars)

Comment: Any idea if this is still valid? The Cornell link is dead. I would hope it's been updated, as nearly everyone and their mom has a TV bigger than 55 inches these days.